# Как задать относительный путь ini, лежащему в папке с программой?

Tags: ini

Честно, я не знаю, можно ли здесь спрашивать о Clickteam Fusion 2.5, но если что, заранее прошу прощения.
Вообщем мне надо задать путь к файлу ini, лежащему в папке с самой программой. То есть не абсолютный, относительный, именно с корневой папкой - папкой программы. Я нашёл, что путь папки программы указывается Appdir$, но к нему нельзя добавить само название файла.[image: Вот...]

Answer (score 0):

Если это кому-то понадобиться, когда-нибудь в 2030)) Короче я сам нашёл: надо в скобки поставить параметр Appdir$ потом + потом "" ну и в них собственно путь к файлу